# Remove share screenshot option - DataTransferManager

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-10

In windows 8.1 apps, while invoking the share UI using

```
 Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
```

we get an option to share the screenshot of the current app by default. Is there a way to remove this feature?

The data I am passing from the app to be shared is a URL.

```
     private void DataTransferManager_DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
     {
          args.Request.Data.SetWebLink(new Uri(myUrl));
     }
```

When the share pane appears, user is presented with an option to share the screen shot also. The scenario is explained in [this link](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-share-screenshots-windows-81-apps)

I tried setting `ApplicationView.IsScreenCaptureEnabled` to false. It still listed "share screenshot". But when tried to share, shared an empty black screen. Can I do something to remove that option from share pane?

Comment: Are you sure that it's there by default, and not provided by some of the app you have installed? Win8.1 programs can register to be share targets and other programs can't disable providing their content to specific other apps. When they share, they share to all who have registered that they can receive such content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, all the apps that I know of, have this option listed, so I would say this is a system built-in option, that you cannot remove in your app code.